# Вызов метода через рефлексию в AppDomain с ограниченными правами

Tags: c#, рефлексия, appdomain

Я создал новый ограниченный AppDomain и загрузил некоторые сборки в этот AppDomain, но когда я пытаюсь вызвать метод через рефлексию (Invoke) возникает 
исключение SecurityException. Если метод вызывать не через рефлексию, то выполняется без ошибки.

Что не хватает для вызова Invoke с помощью рефлексии?

Вот эти разрешения я использую:

```
var ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.BindingRedirects |
                                        SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution |
                                        SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure | SecurityPermissionFlag.Assertion
                                        | SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlThread));
ps.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, pluginPath));
ps.SetPermission(new ReflectionPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

Сам код построения AppDomain c ограниченными правами, strongNames - содержит все сборки для подгружаемого плагина:

```
domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(appDomainName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup, ps,strongNames);

var pluginLoaderObj = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(domain,
    parameters.PathToMainAssembly,
    parameters.MainClass);

plugin = (TPlagin) pluginLoaderObj.Unwrap();
plugin.CallMethod("MethodName"); //тут работает рефлексия
```

Если strongNames не указывать то при CreateInstanceFrom() выходит ошибка:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type:
>   'Development.Service.ClientService`1'.
>   Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base
>   type or be less accessible

Может не правильно передаю?

Когда вызывается метод Invoke(), в `plugin.CallMethod("MethodName")`, выдаёт такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из под FullTrust:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой именно метод вызываете? Также покажите полный текст исключения (`ex.ToString()`). Обычно он содержит информацию о том какое разрешение было запрошено.

Comment: Вызываю метод который возвращает массив байтов:  byte[] GetByteArray(RemoteSession session), ошибка такая:     System.Security.SecurityException: 'Request failed.', значение для FirstPermissionThatFailed 'System.Security.SecurityException

Comment: `SecurityException` желательно рассматривать из `FullTrust` контекста, иначе большинство свойств будут недоступны и выбрасывать новое `SecurityException` при обращении. Относительно вызываемого метода, меня больше интересует не сигнатура, а атрибуты безопасности. В частности, если у Вас есть `MethodInfo mi` представляющий метод, то было бы полезно узнать значение `mi.IsSecurityCritical` и `mi.IsSecuritySafeCritical`.

Comment: IsSecurityCritical  = true, IsSecuritySafeCritical = false, если IsSecurityCritical  тоже false, та же ошибка выходит, но если без рефлексии то метод вызывается без ошибки

Comment: Вызов метода с `IsSecurityCritical = true` и `IsSecuritySafeCritical = false` через рефлексию генерирует запрос на `FullTrust`. Соответственно, Вам необходимо сделать `Assert` на `FullTrust`, пока проход по стеку не дошёл до частично доверенного кода.

Comment: Если перед вызовом запустить FullTrust:  new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)).Assert(), то Invoke() срабатывает, тогда же можно будет в любой момент поменять права и выполнять всё из под FullTrust, или можно как то ограничить эту возможность ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70358/discussion-between-petseral-and-developer).

Comment: @PetSerAl спасибо за пример, оказывается я немного не правильно понимал, SecurityCritical - разрешает использовать методы и тд только из FullTrust, а помеченные как SecuritySafeCritical  в FullTrust сборке разрешает вызов методов из частично доверенного кода, то есть загружённые сборки которые не являются FullTrust подчиняются правам доступа  AppDomain + разрешается вызывать методы из FullTrust сборки которые помечены как SecuritySafeCritical (а из метода SecuritySafeCritical можно если что сделать дополнительный Assert()), верно?

Comment: В принципе верно, хотя есть пара неточностей.

Comment: А можно узнать неточности, пожалуйста?

Comment: `SecurityCritical` нельзя напрямую вызывать из `SecurityTransparent` кода вне зависимости от уровня его привилегий (`FullTrust` или нет). `SecurityTransparent` код (весь частично доверенный код всегда `SecurityTransparent`) может вызывать только другой `SecurityTransparent` код или `SecuritySafeCritical` код. `Assert()` можно делать как из `SecuritySafeCritical`, так и из `SecurityCritical` кода.